# How to start Intent when either actionbar or builtin back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-intent, back-button

So I have an intent that I want to start when either of 2 back buttons is pressed. Either this back button "getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);" or the one that's on all android phones that's built in to the device. I've searched around and could not find a solution.

Here's my code where you can see in the if statement I want the "if back button is pressed" code to be. I appreciate any input!

```
    CheckBox routeCheckBox;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_details);

    //back button for route details view
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //sets actionbar title
    routeName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("routeName");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(routeName);


    ///////checkbox///////
    routeCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.routeCheckBox);

    routeCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
          if (routeCheckBox.isChecked())
          {
              Intent check = new     Intent(RouteDetails.this,MainActivity.class);
              check.putExtra("checkImageResource", R.drawable.checkmark);

  /////////////////// ////////////     
              if ( actionbar back button or the built in backbutton on all   android devices is pressed)
              {
                  startActivity(check);
              } 
     ////////////////////////////////
          }
        }
    });
```

New code Edit:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // your code here
    routeCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (routeCheckBox.isChecked())
            {
                Intent check = new Intent(RouteDetails.this,MainActivity.class);
                check.putExtra("checkImageResource", R.drawable.checkmark);
                startActivity(check);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I put this in my code but now the If statement is not working. It does not pass the checkImageResource to my main activity. Why would this be? Thanks for any help!

Comment: you should remove the "if back button is pressed" statement, that will be called by the system automatically (onBackPressed)..

Comment: I did remove that. I edited my post above to show how I added your code

Comment: the setOnClickListener should be inside onCreate, and only the `if (routeCheckBox.isChecked())` block should be inside onBackPressed